# Existence of a regular smooth curve in $S^2$ tangent to a continuous vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a continuous tangent vector field on $S^2$.

[Hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) asserts that there exists a point $p$ in $S^2$ at which $X(p) = 0$.

I guess that there is a regular smooth curve $\gamma : S^1 \to S^2$ satisfying that $\gamma'(t) = X(\gamma(t))$ for all $t \in S^1$.

However, I cannot prove or disprove it.

Comment: First of all, $X = 0$ is a trivial counterexample and if you want an other one, take $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ unitary and $X : x \mapsto v - \left<x,v\right>x$. For all $x \in \mathbb{S}^2$, $\left<x,X(x)\right> = 0$ so $X$ is tangent to the sphere and the integral curves join $-v$ to $v$ (imagine a compass pointing toward $v$) thus $X$ has no closed integral curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why there should be an integral curve for $X$ which is closed. Take the vector field $X(x)=f(x)x$ for $x\in\mathbb R^2$, where $f$ is a bump function supported in a small ball around zero and transport it to a hemisphere, say via central projection. Then the integral curves of $X$ are parametrizations of pieces of straight lines which (smoothly) stop at some point.On $S^2$ they will correspond to parametrizations of pieces of great circles which then stop. In particular, there is no regular closed curve among the integral curves.